# Вызвать функцию из функции (базовые знания)

Tags: jquery, frontend, javascript

Господа, помогите, разобраться раз и навсегда, jQuery - это, конечно, хорошо, на "база" в первую очередь. Есть код:

```
var checkForms = {
    this.checkItem = function(itemId) {
        return 'checking for item:' + itemId;
    };

    this.getProducts = function(prodId) {
        return 'getting products:' + prodId;
    };

    this.getAddress = function(cityId) {
        return 'getting address from city:' + cityId;
    }
};

var getData = checkForms.getProducts(112);
console.log(getData);
```

Хочу, чтобы запустило `getProduct(prodId)`, но почему-то получаю: `'undefined is not a function'`. И вообще можно "вкратце", верная ли подобная структура, хочу заделать "модульков" для проекта, чтобы иметь общее пространство для переменных внутри каждого модуля и не светить ими "наверх". Видел кучи примеров, но они там мудреные, со всякими "замыканиями" и другими страшными вещами вроде `apply(), .call(), .bind()`, уверен, можно попроще.
P.S. Ну, само собой, чтобы внутри `checkForms` было доступно jQuery.

Comment: С первым разобрался, но как вызвать Ваш второй пример?

http://jsfiddle.net/5hxpg1cw/1/

Comment: Спасибо разобрался, сделайте ответом!

Answer (score 1):

`this.` там не нужен, почему js вообще глотает такое объявление объекта - не знаю, но надо объявлять так:

```
var obj = {
    'checkItem': function () {},
    'getProducts': function () {}
}
```

либо

```
var obj = function() {
    this.checkItem = function () {};
    this.getProducts = function () {};
}
```